# Applications: why are sometimes some characters underlined?

Tags: applications

I just got to mind that some installers / wizards or application sometimes underline a single (or more) characters.

Can someone brighten me up and explain why this is done?

Example:

[image]

I'm asking here because I think it has something to do with UX / Accessibility maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible shortcuts are via the keyboard.

Quote from here: [journalofaccountancy.com/.../thoseunderlinedlettersinthetoolbar.html](https://www.journalofaccountancy.com/issues/2000/sep/thoseunderlinedlettersinthetoolbar.html)

> Those underscores are very useful because they give users an alternative way—without the mouse—to activate many commands.